# Eclipse Building Workspace always slow due to Invoking "Maven Project Builder"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am building a maven project using Eclipse.  When I modify and save the Java file it takes more time to build the workspace.  When I open the progress bar it shows **Invoking "Maven Project Builder"**.

I have searched and tried various options but no luck. I even tried to disable the Maven project Builder from the builder option. If I disable this option it doesn't take that much time but when I run the Maven install I get an error due to disabling of Maven project builder. So I re-enabled the Maven Project builder option.

Kindly give me a permanent solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to uncheck the `Build Automatically` option under `Project` menu in your eclipse. It will prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
yes but if my changes needs to reflect means again i need to enable that option right or again i need to build the project. So again it will take time for building workspace.
My problem is whenever i build the project it takes more time.

Comment: Maybe your project has a reference to another one! Maybe there is an issue with some included jars! Just check it.

Comment: First how many modules do you have? And how long is slow? What kind of project do you have an OSGi project or a plain Java (EE) project?

Comment: I have only one module in my eclipse. When i modify simple java file and if i save that file it is taking almost 2minutes to build the workspace. It is Maven java project not a OSGI project.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a Maven Project in Eclipse stops working without reason. What I'm used to do in these cases is instead of trying to find the root cause of the problem I simply try do execute a couple of cleaning procedures:

1. Try clicking on menu Project -> Clean;
2. Try click with the
   right button on the Project in Project Explorer -> Maven -> Update
   Project;
3. Switch to a new workspace -> Import the Maven project
   again.

Sometimes your workspace crashes without reason. Instead of wasting mental energy it's better trying to isolate the problem answering questions like:

- This problem happens in any workstation or only in mine?
- This problem happens in any Eclipse workspace or only in my current Eclipse workspace?

Try this approach and let me know if it works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried whatever you have mentioned above but still the problem is not yet solved.

1. This problem happens only to me. It is working fine in my colleagues system. Even i have tried to Copy the same eclipse setup in my local but again same issue.

2. This problem exists even if i change my workspace

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. 
Finally i got solution for this issue.
I have modified the settings.xml. Instead of pointing my repository path(/server/.m2/repository) in the server level, i have pointed my  repository path to local repository(c:\repository). so whenever i gave build it would point my local repository and it would compile my java classes. So now my build is doing very fast.

Comment: you have your local repository put on a server?!